# Dynamically updating css brightness of the image in Angular 2 or 4

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-forms

I'm trying to update the brightness of the image dynamically. I'm getting error like this in console

> WARNING: sanitizing unsafe style value filter:brightness(%); (see
>   http://g.co/ng/security#xss).

Here my code

```
<img src="../assets/images/image.png" class="cover-img" alt="image" [style.filter]="'brightness('+ range +'%)'">
```

> range is a variable

please let me know, If there is any alternative ways to achieve this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can solve this problem by sanitize as follows:

In component

```
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';

constructor(private _sanitizer: DomSanitizer){}

 getfilters() {
    return this._sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustStyle('brightness('+ this.brightnessRange +'%)')
}
```

In Html

```
<img src="../assets/images/image.png" class="cover-img" alt="image" [style.filter]="getfilters()">
```

Answer (score 1):

You do this by following.

```
[style.filter]="'brightness('+ range +'%)'"
```

Here range is your ts variable.